# In Matlab, how to quickly select single element of matrix produced by a function?

Tags: matlab

E.g. I have the output of `cov(A,B)`, which is a 2×2 matrix.

I want to select the element in position 2,1 of the matrix.

I can do this by `blah = cov(A,B)` and then select `blah(1,2)`.

This isn't the most efficient way to do it though, and I'd prefer to do it in one line. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am afraid that the only gain in "efficiency" you may expect here is to remove one LOC. Since `cov` is implemented to return the full matrix, it always will, whether you only need 1 element of it is irrelevant. Note that matlab doesn't make any extra copies just because of the assignment to `blah`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`getfield()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html):

```
getfield(cov(A,B), {1,2})
```

The performance difference between this and what you have currently will likely be negligible, however. I personally would prefer just using that temporary variable.

Comment: nothing magical here, do `edit getfield` and you'll see it's basically doing: `c={1,2}; x(c{:})` (a feature called comma separated lists) where `x` is the input to the function `x=cov(A,B);`. The way I see, it is just another layer of indirection :) So just use a temporary variable anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`<stealing brilliance from Amro>`

You can also do this:

```
C = builtin('_paren', cov(A,B), 2, 1);
```

`</stealing brilliance from Amro>`